# Mostrar en un textarea campos seleccionado en un select traídos desde mysql?

Tags: php

Hola quiero saber como puedo hacer que cada vez que seleccione una opcion select se valla agregando a un textarea

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Servicio</label>

     </head>
     <form>
     <?php 
       $query_mostrar_tema = "SELECT * FROM materiales"; 
       $mostrar_tema = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_mostrar_tema ) or die(mysqli_error()); 
       $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema); 
       $totalRows_mostrar_tema = mysqli_num_rows($mostrar_tema); 
        ?> 
       <select id="tema" name="tema" onChange="actualizar()">> 
       <?php do { ?> 
          <option value="<?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['id']?>"><?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['nombre']?> 
          </option> 
               <?php 
               } while ($row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema));
               $rows = mysqli_num_rows($tema); 
               if($rows > 0) { 
                   mysqli_data_seek($tema, 0); 
                   $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tema); 
               } 
               ?> 
        </select>
        <br>
        <textarea id="eltexto" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo con javascript o mejor aun con jQuery.  Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 2):

Desde javascript tenés que capturar el evento `change` del `select` para que cada vez que cambie, tome el valor y lo inserte en el `textarea`.

Como no sé que valores tenés en el html, hice este ejemplo provisoriamente para que logres entender.

```js
// select
var select = document.querySelector('#tema');
// texarea
var textarea = document.querySelector('#eltexto');

// evento change para obtener el valor del select
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // concateno al textarea el valor seleccionado y le agrego
  // un salto de línea
  textarea.value += this.value + '\r\n';
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="tema" id="tema">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="uno">1</option>
    <option value="dos">2</option>
    <option value="tres">3</option>
    <option value="manzana">apple</option>
    <option value="naranja">orange</option>
    <option value="frutilla">strawberry</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea name="eltexto" id="eltexto" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

Acá te dejo también el [link a Codepen](https://codepen.io/kleith/pen/rvQmGR) para que puedas visualizar el mismo ejemplo.